# Multiple select, Collections and Spring 3 web MVC

Tags: java, spring

I'm using a multiple select HTML form input to allow a user to pick a collection of Extensions from a list of all possible Extensions.

The Extension class is quite simple -

```
public class Extension {

 private String number;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 ... getters and setters ...

 @Override
 public String toString() {     
  return new StringBuilder(number).append(" - ")
               .append(firstName).append(" ").append(lastName)
               .toString();
 }  

}
```

Here's my form object -

```
public class BusinessUnitForm {

    private String name;
    private Collection<Extension> extensions;


    public Collection<Extension> getExtensions() {
        return extensions;
    }

    public void setExtensions(Collection<Extension> extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And the controller -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/businessunit")
public class BusinessUnitController {

    ... extension service & getters/setters ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Integer customerId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("customerId");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("bu");

        // this is quite expensive...
        Collection<Extension> allExtensions = extensionService.getAllExtensions(customerId);

        BusinessUnitForm businessUnitForm = new BusinessUnitForm();

        mav.addObject("allExtensions", allExtensions);
        mav.addObject("businessUnitForm", businessUnitForm);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BusinessUnitForm businessUnitForm, BindingResult result) throws Exception {

        // *** BREAKPOINT HERE *** to examine businessUnitForm 

        Integer tenantId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("tenantId");

        // code to process submission 

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("bu"); 
        return mav;
    }
}
```

And finally the view -

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<html>

...

<form:form action="businessunit/create" method="POST" commandName="businessUnitForm" >

 <form:label path="name"></form:label><form:input path="name" />

 <form:select path="extensions" cssClass="multiselect">                      
  <form:options items="${allExtensions}" itemValue="number" />
 </form:select>

 <input type="submit" value="Create" />

</form:form>

...

</html>
```

At the breakpoint shown above in the create controller method, businessUnitForm.extensions is null.  businessUnitForm.name is bound correctly.

I've tried, perhaps misguidedly, making businessUnitForm.extensions a LazyList but this doesn't help.

If I change `BusinessUnitForm.extensions` to be a `Collection` of unspecified type, it is populated successfully with a LinkedHashSet of Strings, containing the values selected.

Maybe I'm expecting too much of Spring, but I was hoping it would be able to use the values from the select, and also the reference data in allExtensions to automagically create a `Collection<Extension>` for me on the businessUnitForm.  I understand the role of CustomCollectionEditors, but was under the impression that this might not be required in Spring 3.

Can Spring 3 populate my `Collection<Extension>` on the BusinessUnitForm without me writing a custom collection editor ?  Some kind of trick with the view, perhaps ?

Thanks in advance ...

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a custom converter that is able to convert the String from the request into an `Extension` object.

And then you must use Collection (or List, or Set) with generic type information.

See this answer for an example of an converter: [Submit Spring Form using Ajax where Entity has Foreign Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269127/submit-spring-form-using-ajax-where-entity-has-foreign-entities/9289829#9289829)

Comment: thank you for your reply Ralph.  I was aware of how to do this with a PropertyEditor but hadn't really looked into the new Conversion stuff.